# Wait until all threads are finished in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run multiple threads simultaneously, and wait until all of them are done before continuing.

```
import subprocess

# I want these to happen simultaneously:
subprocess.call(scriptA + argumentsA)
subprocess.call(scriptA + argumentsB)
subprocess.call(scriptA + argumentsC)

# I want to wait until the above threads are all finished, and then run this:
print("All threads are done.")
```

---

I tried to use `threading` like the example [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/simplistic-python-thread-example/):

```
from threading import Thread
import subprocess

def call_script(args)
    subprocess.call(args)

t1 = Thread(target=call_script, args=(scriptA + argumentsA))
t2 = Thread(target=call_script, args=(scriptA + argumentsB))
t3 = Thread(target=call_script, args=(scriptA + argumentsC))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

# TODO: Wait for all threads to finish.

print("All threads are done.")
```

How do I wait for the threads to finish before running the last line?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You need to use [join](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method of `Thread` object in the end of the script.

```
t1 = Thread(target=call_script, args=(scriptA + argumentsA))
t2 = Thread(target=call_script, args=(scriptA + argumentsB))
t3 = Thread(target=call_script, args=(scriptA + argumentsC))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

Thus the main thread will wait till `t1`, `t2` and `t3` finish execution.

Comment: hmmm - having trouble understanding something, wont this first run t1, wait till its finish, then go to t2..etc,etc ? how do make it all happen at once? i dont see how this would run them at the same time?

Comment: The call to `join` blocks until thread finishes execution. You will have to wait for all of the threads anyway. If `t1` finishes first you will start waiting on `t2` (which might be finished already and you will immediately proceed to wait for `t3`). If `t1` took the longest to execute, when you return from it both `t1` and `t2` will return immediately without blocking.

Comment: you dont understand my question - if i copy the above code to my code - will it work? or am i missing something?

Comment: sorry, I accidentally missed the part that actually starts threads' execution (updated the answer). Yes, the code, as it is now, will work as you expect it.

Comment: okay, i see. now i understand, was a bit confused about it but i think i understand, `join` sort of attaches the current process to the thread and waits till its done, and if t2 finishs before t1 then when t1 is done it will check for t2 being done see that it is, and then check t3..etc..etc.. and then only when all are done it will continue. awesome.

Comment: say t1 takes the longest, but t2 has an exception. what happens then? can you catch that exception or check whether t2 finished ok or not?

Comment: i think use the `for` loop is better. but your answer is ok.

Comment: but t2.join has to wait for t1, t3.join has to wait for t2?

Comment: @datdinhquoc you intend to wait for all the threads' completion anyway. If the thread is already completed when you call join, the call should be very fast and non-blocking. Thus the overall wait time should be dominated by the slowest thread's execution.

Answer (score 265):

Put the threads in a list, [`.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) each thread, and then [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) each thread:

```
threads = [
    Thread(...),
    Thread(...),
    Thread(...),
]

# Start all threads.
for t in threads:
    t.start()

# Wait for all threads to finish.
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: could i technically do `threads.append(Thread(target=call_script, args=(scriptA + argumentsA)))` ? and skip a bunch of code?

Comment: Yes, that would work but is harder to understand. You should always try to find a balance between compact code and "readability". Remember: Code is written once but read many times. So it's more important that it's easy to understand.

Comment: @Aaron DIgull I understand that.What I mean is that I would just do a `for x in threads: x.join()` rather than using list comprehantion

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu: I'm still wondering if there is a more readable and efficient solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428602/how-inefficient-is-a-list-comprehension-if-you-dont-assign-it

Comment: one x.join will block the next x.join in the loop?

Comment: @DanD. Each `.join()` waits for only its respective thread to end. If you attempt to `.join()` a thread that is already done, nothing happens, and it just moves to the next line of code.

Answer (score 68):

In Python3, since Python 3.2 there is a new approach to reach the same result, that I personally prefer to the traditional thread creation/start/join, package `concurrent.futures`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` the code would be:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time
    
def call_script(ordinal, arg):
    print('Thread', ordinal, 'argument:', arg)
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Thread', ordinal, 'Finished')
    
args = ['argumentsA', 'argumentsB', 'argumentsC']
    
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    ordinal = 1
    for arg in args:
        executor.submit(call_script, ordinal, arg)
        ordinal += 1
print('All tasks has been finished')
```

The output of the previous code is something like:

```
Thread 1 argument: argumentsA
Thread 2 argument: argumentsB
Thread 1 Finished
Thread 2 Finished
Thread 3 argument: argumentsC
Thread 3 Finished
All tasks has been finished
```

One of the advantages is that you can control the throughput setting the max concurrent workers.

To use multiprocessing instead, you can use [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor).

Comment: but how can you tell when all threads in the threadpool have finished?

Comment: As you can see in the example, the code after the `with` statement is executed when all task have finished.

Comment: this doesn't work. Try doing something really long in threads. Your print statement will execute before thread finishes

Comment: @Pranalee, That code works, I've updated the code to add the output lines. You cannot see the "All task..." before all threads are finished, That is how the `with` statement works by design in this case. Anyway, you can always open a new question in SO and post your code so we can help you to find out what is happening in your case.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign you can use `concurrent.futures.wait` function, you can see a [real example here](https://github.com/shaftoe/api-l3x-in/blob/b82e3a888ecff261bcae8ffd7c8a9846ba616391/lib/stacks/pagespeed/lambdas/pagespeed_poller.py#L69)

Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait

Comment: This does work, because base `Executor` explicitly calls `self.shutdown(wait=True)` in its `__exit__`.

Comment: BE AWARE for a long args - you will end up with tons of memory usage - consider using semaphore.

Answer (score 41):

I prefer using list comprehension based on an input list:

```
inputs = [scriptA + argumentsA, scriptA + argumentsB, ...]
threads = [Thread(target=call_script, args=(i)) for i in inputs]
[t.start() for t in threads]
[t.join() for t in threads]
```

Comment: Checked answer explains well but this one is shorter and doesn't require ugly repetitions. Just a nice answer. :)

Comment: List comprehension just for side effects is usually depreciated*.  But in this use case, it seems to be a good idea.
*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: @VinayakKaniyarakkal `for t in threads:t.start()` isn't it better?

Answer (score 7):

You can have class something like below from which you can add 'n' number of functions or console_scripts you want to execute in parallel passion and start the execution and wait for all jobs to complete..

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class ProcessParallel(object):
    """
    To Process the  functions parallely

    """    
    def __init__(self, *jobs):
        """
        """
        self.jobs = jobs
        self.processes = []

    def fork_processes(self):
        """
        Creates the process objects for given function deligates
        """
        for job in self.jobs:
            proc  = Process(target=job)
            self.processes.append(proc)

    def start_all(self):
        """
        Starts the functions process all together.
        """
        for proc in self.processes:
            proc.start()

    def join_all(self):
        """
        Waits untill all the functions executed.
        """
        for proc in self.processes:
            proc.join()


def two_sum(a=2, b=2):
    return a + b

def multiply(a=2, b=2):
    return a * b


#How to run:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #note: two_sum, multiply can be replace with any python console scripts which
    #you wanted to run parallel..
    procs =  ProcessParallel(two_sum, multiply)
    #Add all the process in list
    procs.fork_processes()
    #starts  process execution 
    procs.start_all()
    #wait until all the process got executed
    procs.join_all()
```

Comment: This is multiprocessing. Question was about https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: I can recomment multiprocessing too, but not this way. If you just create processes and not care about system resources it can froze system. If you don't know number of processes it is better to use .map

Answer (score 3):

I just came across the same problem where I needed to wait for all the threads which were created using the for loop.I just tried out the following piece of code.It may not be the perfect solution but I thought it would be a simple solution to test:

```
for t in threading.enumerate():
    try:
        t.join()
    except RuntimeError as err:
        if 'cannot join current thread' in err:
            continue
        else:
            raise
```

Answer (score 3):

From the `threading` [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

> There is a “main thread” object; this corresponds to the initial
>   thread of control in the Python program. It is not a daemon thread.
>
> There is the possibility that “dummy thread objects” are created.
>   These are thread objects corresponding to “alien threads”, which are
>   threads of control started outside the threading module, such as
>   directly from C code. Dummy thread objects have limited functionality;
>   they are always considered alive and daemonic, and cannot be `join()`ed.
>   They are never deleted, since it is impossible to detect the
>   termination of alien threads.

So, to catch those two cases when you are not interested in keeping a list of the threads you create:

```
import threading as thrd


def alter_data(data, index):
    data[index] *= 2


data = [0, 2, 6, 20]

for i, value in enumerate(data):
    thrd.Thread(target=alter_data, args=[data, i]).start()

for thread in thrd.enumerate():
    if thread.daemon:
        continue
    try:
        thread.join()
    except RuntimeError as err:
        if 'cannot join current thread' in err.args[0]:
            # catchs main thread
            continue
        else:
            raise
```

Whereupon:

```
>>> print(data)
[0, 4, 12, 40]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, something like

```
for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t.daemon:
        t.join()
```

Comment: I have tried this code but not sure about its working because the last instruction of my code was printed which was after this for loop and still the process was not terminated.

Answer (score 0):

using only join can result in **false-possitive** interaction with thread. Like said in docs :

> When the timeout argument is present and not None, it should be a
> floating point number specifying a timeout for the operation in
> seconds (or fractions thereof). As join() always returns None, you
> must call isAlive() after join() to decide whether a timeout happened
> – if the thread is still alive, the join() call timed out.

and illustrative piece of code:

```
threads = []
for name in some_data:
    new = threading.Thread(
        target=self.some_func,
        args=(name,)
    )
    threads.append(new)
    new.start()
    
over_threads = iter(threads)
curr_th = next(over_threads)
while True:
    curr_th.join()
    if curr_th.is_alive():
        continue
    try:
        curr_th = next(over_threads)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) (or [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)).
Then, call [`.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) on your desired function `func`, and a list of arguments `xs`:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(xs)) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(func, xs))
```

`.map` returns an iterator containing the return value of each function, which we collect into a list.

---

In your case:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

argss = [
    ["python", "scriptA.py", "a"],
    ["python", "scriptA.py", "b"],
    ["python", "scriptA.py", "c"],
]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(argss)) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(call_script, argss))
```