# More Compact List Comprehension Where Iteration Variable is Unused

Tags: python, iterator, generator, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I have several sampling functions that need to be called for a certain amount of times as in the following instruction:

```
samples = [do_sampling() for _unused in range(n_samples)]
```

I wonder, is there a more compact way to express that statement, especially by avoiding the `_unused` variable?

Comment: Are you building a list, or are you using the list comprehension syntax as a means to loop? Why the need to be more compact? Why not *more readable for future maintainers*?

Comment: See [Side-effects in python map (python "do" block)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14447560) and [How (in)efficient is a list comprehension if you don't assign it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21428602) for discussions on the latter use.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it's just a list built by sampling a number of times independently, with no side effects and no parameters to the sampling function. Any suggestion on how to make it more readable is well accepted.

Comment: You have it as readable as it gets. I use `_` for the loop variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a better way to do this that I'm aware of. The convention is to do this:

```
samples = [do_sampling() for _ in range(n_samples)]
```

If you're using Python 2.x and not Python 3.x, you can gain a performance improvement by using a generator-version of range, `xrange()`, rather than `range()`:

```
samples = [do_sampling() for _ in xrange(n_samples)]
```

The `_` variable is typically used as Pythonic notation for a discarded, unused variable.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to build a list from the `do_sampling()` return values, there is no more compact syntax.

The Python convention is to use `_` for the *I'm ignoring this* variables:

```
samples = [do_sampling() for _ in range(n_samples)]
```