# How to run third function after second function is executed?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

These 3 functions are working, but the last one needs to wait till the first and second are executed. I can use `time.sleep()`, but I think this is not the right way. How do I fix it?

```
 def convert_and_save(self):
    self.open()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.convertThread.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.saveThread.start()
```

---

```
def convert_and_save(self):
    self.open()
    self.convertThread.start()
    self.saveThread.start()
    self.convertThread.join()
    self.saveThread.join()
```

error: `AttributeError: 'ConvertThread' object has no attribute 'join'`

---

This works but suspendig GUI :(

```
def convert_and_save(self):
    self.open()
    self.convertThread.start()
    while self.convertThread.isFinished() == False:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    self.saveThread.start()
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Comment: Question is update of this part of code where is the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python multithreading wait till all threads finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968689/python-multithreading-wait-till-all-threads-finished)

Comment: @KenY-N I made this in my second example, but I have an error: `AttributeError: 'ConvertThread' object has no attribute 'join'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
self.convertThread.join()
self.saveThread.join()
```

to wait until both threads have ended their execution.

Have a look at `help("threading.Thread")` for more things that you can do with threads.

Whole code:

```
    def convert_and_save(self):
        self.open()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.convertThread.start()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.saveThread.start()

        self.convertThread.join()
        self.saveThread.join()

        # This is executed when both threads stopped
```

Comment: Thak you, but I don't want using `time.sleep` function.
Now I have error: `AttributeError: 'ConvertThread' object has no attribute 'join'` Question is updated.

Comment: Now I see, what @khelwood means. I assumed a self.convertThread to be a threading.Thread object. That seems not to be the the case. What can a ConvertThread do? Please consider rewriting your question.

Comment: `ConvertThread` converting a lot of strings (changing). And thats why saving (`saveThread`) need wait till `ConvertThread` will be not finish.
Question is updated - but this code also suspend GUI.