# How to wait for a thread to finished before moving to next one in loop without freezing gui in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to wait for a thread before moving to next one. I was using .join() method but that freezes me gui. I want my gui to be responsive meanwhile. Here is my code so far.

```
  class mainqueue:
      def __init__(self):
          self.mainQueue=queue.Queue()

      def addItem(self,q):
          self.mainQueue.put(q)

      def startConverting(self,funcName):
          for i in range(2):
              print("starting thread {}".format(i))
              t = Thread(target = self.threaded_function)
              t.start()
              t.join()

      def threaded_function(self):

          time.sleep(5)
          print(self.mainQueue.get())


  m=mainqueue()
  def helloCallBack():
     m.addItem("a")
     m.addItem("b")
     m.addItem("c")
     m.startConverting("test")

  B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)

  B.pack()
  top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968689/python-multithreading-wait-till-all-threads-finished

Comment: "I want to wait for a thread before moving to next one" - then why are these two different threads?

Comment: if I am getting your question then, I want to dequeue one after another, obviously after previous ones completition. These two, may be more depending on the numbers of item i want to dequeue.

Comment: @Xion that .joins() method itself is hanging my gui.