# How to wait till all threads are executed without using thread.join()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am working on a code where threads are generated in a recursive function. So its tedious to follow all threads. Thread.join() is not feasible. You can do it but with a lot of effort. What I want is to wait till all threads(child process) are completed, before printing result generated after running threads. I guess you can get the gist of the problem. All I want is to execute a statement just before exiting the main program.

Comment: Can't you resort to appending threads to a threads list and then `[thread.join() for thread in threads]`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968689/python-multithreading-wait-till-all-threads-finished) answer helps?

Comment: You want to wait for threads to die. That's what `join()` _does_.  How is it not "feasible?" Why can't you make a list? Every time you create a thread, add the `Thread` object to the list.  When it's time to wait for all of the threads to die, iterate over the list and `join()` each one.

Comment: Or create a list of the threads and keep iterating over it until all are `not lst[i].is_alive()`. This is a bad practice called "busy waiting" however...

Comment: Re, "...threads are generated in a recursive function..." That sounds *very* suspicious. What are those threads doing? Why aren't you using a _[thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_?  (as in, djoffe's answer, below)

Comment: martineau I mentioned that I can't track all threads. Its possible to do as you say if I can track threads. Tracking threads is difficult. It's not like I am using specific number of threads or starting them at a time. So using thread.join is not feasible

Comment: Solomon Slow thanks. I am new to python so not much knowledgeable. I will try using thread pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) package?

You can instantiate a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and start your threads by submitting to it.
Then call the executor's `shutdown(wait=True)` function to wait for all threads to complete.

Alternatively, use a `with ThreadPoolExecutor as e:` statement. When you exit the `with` block, all your threads are completed.

Comment: Note: This doesn't actually create a thread per task (it's a pool of thread workers). That said, you usually don't *want* a thread per task for a ton of small tasks, so this is likely better than the OP's proposed solution.

Comment: Shadow ranger can you elaborate what you mentioned? Are you talking about djoffe answer?

Comment: @KRISHNAI: Executors create a pool of workers (threads for `ThreadPoolExecutor`) immediately, all of which listen to a queue for work items. `submit` doesn't launch new threads, it just packages up the task and shoves it on the queue to be pulled by the first available worker. In practice, this is usually better than a thread per worker, since the cost of launching a thread is non-trivial, and for 1000+ work items, you might not be *able* to run that many threads simultaneously.

Comment: Oh! Thanks ShadowRanger