# How to make a python thread dependent on the completion of another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

Basically I want make like 15000 get requests of the form GET www.somewebsite.com/archive/1, www.somewebsite.com/archive/2, and write the content to its own file locally. But doing all those in order takes a bit. And doing them all with their own thread results in all sorts of IO and HTTP errors. But if I do say 50 at a time it works fine. What I want to do is create a chunk thread that I spawn 50 threads off of, and then spawn another chunk thread when that one is finished. But I haven't found a way to do this.

I need a way to say "don't execute any more lines until this thread is completed" or a way to queue up threads that get executed asynchronously in order.

Answer (score 0):

"You need to use join method of Thread object in the end of the script."

This has been stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968689/python-multithreading-wait-till-all-threads-finished) by [maksim skurydzin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276274/maksim-skurydzin).

You might also want to take a look at the multiprocessing class [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in library [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) that will allow you to implement simple batch processing with a queue.

```
import multiprocessing

static_input = range(100)
chunksize = 10

def work(item):
    return "Number " + str(item)

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for out in pool.imap_unordered(work, static_input, chunksize):
        print(out)
```