# How to call a module object?

Tags: python, module, ant-colony

I tried to run this Ant Colony algorithm code (`ant_colony.py`) in Python:

```
from threading import Thread

class ant_colony:
    class ant(Thread):
        def __init__(self, init_location, possible_locations, pheromone_map, distance_callback, alpha, beta, first_pass=False):
            
            Thread.__init__(self)
            
            self.init_location = init_location
            self.possible_locations = possible_locations            
            self.route = []
            self.distance_traveled = 0.0
            self.location = init_location
            self.pheromone_map = pheromone_map
            self.distance_callback = distance_callback
            self.alpha = alpha
            self.beta = beta
            self.first_pass = first_pass
            
            self._update_route(init_location)
            
            self.tour_complete = False
            
        def run(self):
            
            while self.possible_locations:
                next = self._pick_path()
                self._traverse(self.location, next)
                
            self.tour_complete = True
        
        def _pick_path(self):
            
            if self.first_pass:
                import random
                return random.choice(self.possible_locations)
            
            attractiveness = dict()
            sum_total = 0.0
            
            for possible_next_location in self.possible_locations:
                
                pheromone_amount = float(self.pheromone_map[self.location][possible_next_location])
                distance = float(self.distance_callback(self.location, possible_next_location))
                
                
                attractiveness[possible_next_location] = pow(pheromone_amount, self.alpha)*pow(1/distance, self.beta)
                sum_total += attractiveness[possible_next_location]
            
            
            if sum_total == 0.0:
                
                def next_up(x):
                    import math
                    import struct
                    
                    if math.isnan(x) or (math.isinf(x) and x > 0):
                        return x

                    
                    if x == 0.0:
                        x = 0.0

                    n = struct.unpack('<q', struct.pack('<d', x))[0]
                    
                    if n >= 0:
                        n += 1
                    else:
                        n -= 1
                    return struct.unpack('<d', struct.pack('<q', n))[0]
                    
                for key in attractiveness:
                    attractiveness[key] = next_up(attractiveness[key])
                sum_total = next_up(sum_total)
            
            
            import random
            toss = random.random()
                    
            cummulative = 0
            for possible_next_location in attractiveness:
                weight = (attractiveness[possible_next_location] / sum_total)
                if toss <= weight + cummulative:
                    return possible_next_location
                cummulative += weight
        
        def _traverse(self, start, end):
            
            self._update_route(end)
            self._update_distance_traveled(start, end)
            self.location = end
        
        def _update_route(self, new):
            
            self.route.append(new)
            self.possible_locations.remove(new)
            
        def _update_distance_traveled(self, start, end):
            
            self.distance_traveled += float(self.distance_callback(start, end))
    
        def get_route(self):
            if self.tour_complete:
                return self.route
            return None
            
        def get_distance_traveled(self):
            if self.tour_complete:
                return self.distance_traveled
            return None
        
    def __init__(self, nodes, distance_callback, start=None, ant_count=50, alpha=.5, beta=1.2,  pheromone_evaporation_coefficient=.40, pheromone_constant=1000.0, iterations=80):
        
        if type(nodes) is not dict:
            raise TypeError("nodes must be dict")
        
        if len(nodes) < 1:
            raise ValueError("there must be at least one node in dict nodes")
        
        
        self.id_to_key, self.nodes = self._init_nodes(nodes)
        
        self.distance_matrix = self._init_matrix(len(nodes))
        
        self.pheromone_map = self._init_matrix(len(nodes))
        
        self.ant_updated_pheromone_map = self._init_matrix(len(nodes))
        
        
        if not callable(distance_callback):
            raise TypeError("distance_callback is not callable, should be method")
            
        self.distance_callback = distance_callback
        
        
        if start is None:
            self.start = 0
        else:
            self.start = None
            #init start to internal id of node id passed
            for key, value in self.id_to_key.items():
                if value == start:
                    self.start = key
            
            #if we didn't find a key in the nodes passed in, then raise
            if self.start is None:
                raise KeyError("Key: " + str(start) + " not found in the nodes dict passed.")
        
        
        if type(ant_count) is not int:
            raise TypeError("ant_count must be int")
            
        if ant_count < 1:
            raise ValueError("ant_count must be >= 1")
        
        self.ant_count = ant_count
        
        
        if (type(alpha) is not int) and type(alpha) is not float:
            raise TypeError("alpha must be int or float")
        
        if alpha < 0:
            raise ValueError("alpha must be >= 0")
        
        self.alpha = float(alpha)
        
        
        if (type(beta) is not int) and type(beta) is not float:
            raise TypeError("beta must be int or float")
            
        if beta < 1:
            raise ValueError("beta must be >= 1")
            
        self.beta = float(beta)
        
        
        if (type(pheromone_evaporation_coefficient) is not int) and type(pheromone_evaporation_coefficient) is not float:
            raise TypeError("pheromone_evaporation_coefficient must be int or float")
        
        self.pheromone_evaporation_coefficient = float(pheromone_evaporation_coefficient)
        
        #pheromone_constant
        if (type(pheromone_constant) is not int) and type(pheromone_constant) is not float:
            raise TypeError("pheromone_constant must be int or float")
        
        self.pheromone_constant = float(pheromone_constant)
        
        #iterations
        if (type(iterations) is not int):
            raise TypeError("iterations must be int")
        
        if iterations < 0:
            raise ValueError("iterations must be >= 0")
            
        self.iterations = iterations
        
        #other internal variable init
        self.first_pass = True
        self.ants = self._init_ants(self.start)
        self.shortest_distance = None
        self.shortest_path_seen = None
        
    def _get_distance(self, start, end):
        
        if not self.distance_matrix[start][end]:
            distance = self.distance_callback(self.nodes[start], self.nodes[end])
            
            if (type(distance) is not int) and (type(distance) is not float):
                raise TypeError("distance_callback should return either int or float, saw: "+ str(type(distance)))
            
            self.distance_matrix[start][end] = float(distance)
            return distance
        return self.distance_matrix[start][end]
        
    def _init_nodes(self, nodes):
        
        id_to_key = dict()
        id_to_values = dict()
        
        id = 0
        for key in sorted(nodes.keys()):
            id_to_key[id] = key
            id_to_values[id] = nodes[key]
            id += 1
            
        return id_to_key, id_to_values
        
    def _init_matrix(self, size, value=0.0):
        
        ret = []
        for row in range(size):
            ret.append([float(value) for x in range(size)])
        return ret
    
    def _init_ants(self, start):
        
        #allocate new ants on the first pass
        if self.first_pass:
            return [self.ant(start, self.nodes.keys(), self.pheromone_map, self._get_distance,
                self.alpha, self.beta, first_pass=True) for x in range(self.ant_count)]
        #else, just reset them to use on another pass
        for ant in self.ants:
            ant.__init__(start, self.nodes.keys(), self.pheromone_map, self._get_distance, self.alpha, self.beta)
    
    def _update_pheromone_map(self):
        
        #always a square matrix
        for start in range(len(self.pheromone_map)):
            for end in range(len(self.pheromone_map)):
                #decay the pheromone value at this location
                #tau_xy <- (1-rho)*tau_xy   (ACO)
                self.pheromone_map[start][end] = (1-self.pheromone_evaporation_coefficient)*self.pheromone_map[start][end]
                
                #then add all contributions to this location for each ant that travered it
                #(ACO)
                #tau_xy <- tau_xy + delta tau_xy_k
                #   delta tau_xy_k = Q / L_k
                self.pheromone_map[start][end] += self.ant_updated_pheromone_map[start][end]
    
    def _populate_ant_updated_pheromone_map(self, ant):
        
        route = ant.get_route()
        for i in range(len(route)-1):
            #find the pheromone over the route the ant traversed
            current_pheromone_value = float(self.ant_updated_pheromone_map[route[i]][route[i+1]])
        
            #update the pheromone along that section of the route
            #(ACO)
            #   delta tau_xy_k = Q / L_k
            new_pheromone_value = self.pheromone_constant/ant.get_distance_traveled()
            
            self.ant_updated_pheromone_map[route[i]][route[i+1]] = current_pheromone_value + new_pheromone_value
            self.ant_updated_pheromone_map[route[i+1]][route[i]] = current_pheromone_value + new_pheromone_value
        
    def mainloop(self):
        
        
        for _ in range(self.iterations):
            #start the multi-threaded ants, calls ant.run() in a new thread
            for ant in self.ants:
                ant.start()
            
            #source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11968818/5343977
            #wait until the ants are finished, before moving on to modifying shared resources
            for ant in self.ants:
                ant.join()
            
            for ant in self.ants:   
                #update ant_updated_pheromone_map with this ant's constribution of pheromones along its route
                self._populate_ant_updated_pheromone_map(ant)
                
                #if we haven't seen any paths yet, then populate for comparisons later
                if not self.shortest_distance:
                    self.shortest_distance = ant.get_distance_traveled()
                
                if not self.shortest_path_seen:
                    self.shortest_path_seen = ant.get_route()
                    
                #if we see a shorter path, then save for return
                if ant.get_distance_traveled() < self.shortest_distance:
                    self.shortest_distance = ant.get_distance_traveled()
                    self.shortest_path_seen = ant.get_route()
            
            #decay current pheromone values and add all pheromone values we saw during traversal (from ant_updated_pheromone_map)
            self._update_pheromone_map()
            
            #flag that we finished the first pass of the ants traversal
            if self.first_pass:
                self.first_pass = False
            
            #reset all ants to default for the next iteration
            self._init_ants(self.start)
            
            #reset ant_updated_pheromone_map to record pheromones for ants on next pass
            self.ant_updated_pheromone_map = self._init_matrix(len(self.nodes), value=0)
        
        #translate shortest path back into callers node id's
        ret = []
        for id in self.shortest_path_seen:
            ret.append(self.id_to_key[id])
        
        return ret
```

and my module-test file is:

```
import ant_colony
import math
            
    
test_nodes = {0: (0, 7), 1: (3, 9), 2: (12, 4), 3: (14, 11), 4: (8, 11) ,5: (15, 6), 6: (6, 15), 7: (15, 9), 8: (12, 10), 9: (10, 7)}
    
    
def distance(start, end):
    x_distance = abs(start[0] - end[0])
    y_distance = abs(start[1] - end[1]) 
    return math.sqrt(pow(x_distance, 2) + pow(y_distance, 2))
    
colony = ant_colony(test_nodes, distance)
answer = colony.mainloop()
print(answer)
```

but when it runs, this error appears:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried a lot of ways but they didn't work at all. I tried to test two coordinates instead of `distance`, I tried to test using arguments and so on, but they did not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that error says `module` object is not callable. Because when you wrote

```py
import ant_colony
```

What you did was import that whole module when what you really wanted was just the class
so you can go ahead and do

```py
from ant_colony import ant_colony
```

and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You are importing module but not a class. Replace this line of code:

```py
import ant_colony
```

with this line of code:

```py
from ant_colony import ant_colony
```

What's the difference? In my example you are importing class called `ant_colony` from file called `ant_colony`. The first thing is path to file and the second thing is the name of class, function etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it as `ant_colony.ant_colony(...)` , not `ant_colony(...)`
See this thread [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: If you feel that another Q&A pair also answer this question, please flag this question as a duplicate.